# Keyboard shortсut invoke Console in broken centos

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, centos, console

Which is combination of keys to open console. I need repair a broken gnome Centos. There should be something like alt+f1 in Fedora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on exactly *how* and *why* it's broken, as well as which stage of the boot process you try it in.

Various things to try:

- If the brokenness isn't because Xorg is hanging or crashing, you can use [the VT Switch keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) to switch to a virtual console. This won't work if you have broken graphics drivers, but you may be able to override it and get back to a console anyway if you use the next option. <kbd>Alt+F2</kbd> is a common way to switch out of VT-1 to a console (the reason <kbd>Alt+F1</kbd> doesn't work is likely that your X server may be running already on VT-1). You may also have to add <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to the key combinations if you're in Xorg.
- If your kernel has support for it compiled-in, you can use [Magic SysRq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) key combination: Alt+SysRq+r (for a standard US QWERTY keyboard; see the wikipedia article for others.) Once you do this, try the VT switch key combo.
- Try booting into "recovery" or "single" mode: when booting, interrupt GRUB by pressing a key, then edit the kernel command line: remove `nosplash`, `silent`, `quiet` (if they exist) and add `single` or `recovery`. This should boot up without Kernel Mode Setting and without trying to start Xorg; you should then be able to login to the command line.
- Try putting the hard drive into another system (or boot another OS on the same system) and perform appropriate fixes in the config file(s) to get it back to a bootable state.

Comment: upvoted for adding `Ctrl` to the `alt+f1` or trying to get TTY2 with `ctrl+alt+f2`